# Trying to understand an application of Hahn Banach extension theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, dual-spaces, hahn-banach-theorem

In my lectures we were proving some features of metric characterisations of non-reflexivity of a Banach space.

Now one of the statements that we proved was that if $X$ is non-reflexive, then $\forall \theta \in (0,1), \ \exists$ a sequence $(x_i)_{i=1}^\infty \subset B_X$ and $(f_i)_{i=1}^\infty \subset B_{X^*}$ such that $f_i(x_j) = \theta$ if $i \leq j$ and is $0$ otherwise.

Now the start of the proof apparently uses Hahn Banach, but I am not exactly sure how:

> Since $X$ is a proper closed subset of $X^{**}$, then $\exists T\in X^{***}$ such that $T|_X = 0$ and $||T|| = 1$.

I apologise if I have missed a subtlety in one of the many versions of the Hahn Banach extension I have come across, but as far as I can tell the one that has been applied is:

> For a real vector space $X$ and a subset $Y$, then given $g\in Y^*, \exists \ f \in X^*$ such that $f|_Y = g$ and $||f||=||g||$

It is the last part that is confusing me. It seems that the linear map $T\in X^{***}$ in the proof has been chosen to restrict to the zero map on $X$, but then the norm should be $0$ also by the Hahn Banach. I have not seen a version of the Hahn Banach that would allow us to extend a zero linear map to some non-zero normed map on the whole space.

EDIT:

As it was requested, I am giving the whole theorem and proof given in lectures below. This was taught as part of a course on metric embeddings, and was in the section on the Ribe program. The ultimate goal in this section was to obtain a metric characterisation of superreflexivity.

Note that I am in fact still puzzled by the original question. A comment pointed to a text which I do not have access to. The fundamental issue is that the application of Hahn Banach seems to be extending the zero map defined on the proper subspace $X\subset X^{**}$ (for non-reflexive X). But the zero map has vanishing norm. And as far as I can see, every Hahn Banach extension preserves the norm. Here goes with the theorem anyway...

> Theorem 1: Let $X$ be a Banach space. The following are eqivalent:
>
> i)$X$ is non-reflexive
>
> ii) $\forall \theta \in (0,1),  \exists  (x_i)_{i=1}^{\infty}
> > \subset B_X$ and $(f_i)_{i=1}^{\infty} \subset B_{X^*}$ such that
>   $f_i(x_j) = \theta,   i\leq j$ and is $0$ otherwise.
>
> iii) $\exists \theta \in (0,1)$ such that the above holds.
>
> iv) $\forall \theta \in (0,1), \ \exists \ (x_i)_{i=1}^\infty \in B_X$
>   such that $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}, d(conv\{x_1,...,x_n\},
>  conv\{x_{n+1},...\})\geq \theta$. 'conv' denotes the convex hull.
>
> v) $\exists \theta$ such that the above holds.

Proof:

The proof makes use of Hahn Banach extension theorem and heavy use of the following lemma 2. We also use lemma 3 and 4 at the end. The proof of lemma 2 just uses Hahn Banach, and that of lemma 3 is easy and of lemma 4 uses Goldstine and Banach Alaoglu theorem.

> Lemma 2:
>
> Let $\phi \in X^{**}, ||\phi ||<M$ and $E\subset X^* , \dim E < \infty$;
>   then $\exists x \in X$ such that $\hat{x}(f)=\phi(f) \forall f \in E$
>   and $||x||<M$
>
> Lemma 3:
>
> For $C$ a convex subset of a Banach space $X$, $C$ is $||.||$ closed (norm
>   closed) iff is w closed (weak topology)
>
> Lemma 4:
>
> $X$ is reflexiive iff $(B_X, w)$ is compact

First we show i)$\implies$ ii). This uses argument by induction.

First, **(and this is the claim I do not understand)** by Hahn Banach, we have a linear map $T\in X^{***}$ such that $T|_X = 0 , ||T|| = 1$. Then, fix $\theta \in (0,1)$. We have a $\phi \in B_{X^{**}}$ and specifically $||\phi |<1$ (in geneal our balls are closed here) such that $\theta < \lambda = T(\phi) \leq ||T||||\phi|| = ||\phi|| <1$

Now since $\theta <||\phi||<1$, we have an $f_1\in B_{X^*}$ such that $\phi(f_1) = \theta$ and morewover using lemma 2, we have an $x_1\in B_X, ||x_1||<1$ which agrees with $\phi$ on $f_1$, that is $f_1(x_1)=\theta$.

Now, assume we have $(x_i)_{i=1}^n $ and $(f_i)_{i=1}^n$ which satisfy the condition in ii), and also that $\phi(f_i)=\theta, \forall i$.  recall $T(x_i)=0 \forall i$, $T(\phi)=\lambda$, $||T||=1 < \frac{\lambda}{\theta}$. So now we pply lemma 2 on $T$, i.e. we have a $g\in X*$ such that $||g||<\frac{\lambda}{\theta}$ and $\phi(g) = \lambda, g(x_i) = 0$. So now letting $f_{n+1} = \frac{\theta}{\lambda}g$ gives $\phi(f_{n+1})=\theta$ and $f_{n+1}(x_i)=0 , i\in {1,2,...,n}$. We obtain the required $x_{n+1}$ by application of lemma 2 with $\phi$. i.e. we have an $x_{n+1}\in B_X, ||x||<1$ and $f_{n+1}(x_{n+1}) = \theta$. Continue inductively.

Now ii) $\implies$ iii) is obvious. And iv) $\implies$ v) is also. We show ii) $\implies$ iv) and iii) $\implies v)$ and then v) $\implies$ i). Then we are done.

Fix $\theta \in (0,1)$, whether it is the arbitrary one in ii) or the one claimed to exist in iii). And we have $(x_i)\in B_X$ and $(f_i)\in B_{X^*}$ such that the conditions stated in ii) holds. And take some $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Now take arbitrary finite linear combinations that are in the convex hull i.e. $\Sigma_{i=1}^n t_ix_i$ and $\Sigma_{i=n+1}^\infty t_ix_i$ with $t_i\geq 0$ and $\Sigma t_i = 1$ in each sum, and only finitely many of the $t_i$ non-zero. Then since $||f_{n+1}||<1$ we have

$||\Sigma_{i=1}^nt_ix_i - \Sigma_{i=n+1}^\infty t_ix_i|| \ \geq \ |f_{n+1}(\Sigma_{i=1}^nt_ix_i - \Sigma_{i=n+1}^\infty t_ix_i)| = \Sigma_{n+1}^\infty \theta t_i = \theta$.

In fact, I would use a strict $>$ in the above for a stronger statement but we used $\geq$. Perhaps it has to do with whether we allow infinte sums...

Now for v) $\implies$ i). We assume v) and assume X is reflexive to obtain a contradiction. Let $C_n$ be the convex hull  $conv\{x_{n+1},x_{n+2},...\}$ which is a convex subset of $B_X$. Let $\overline{C_n}$ denote the norm closure of $C_n$ (so it is norm-closed and convex).  By lemma 3, we thus have that $\overline{C_n}$ is weak-closed $\forall n$.

Now note that $\overline{C_1} \supset \overline{C_2} \supset ...$, the intersection of finitely many of these is non-empty. Thus from the assumption that X is relfexive, and from lemma 4 which gives us that $B_X$ is thus weak-closed, we have that $\cap \overline{C_n} \neq \emptyset$ and hence we have some $x\in \cap \overline{C_n} \subset B_X$.

Now take the $\theta \in (0,1)$ which we obtain from v).  Since $x\in \overline{C_1}$ we have some $y\in C_1$ such that $||x-y||<\frac{\theta}{3}$ *(this is another point that I'm not seeing, though I suspect it is 'obvious')*

Choose $n$ such that $y\in conv\{x_1,x_2,...,x_n\}$. Since $x \in \overline{C_n}$ then $\exists z\in C_n$ such that $||x-z||<\frac{\theta}{3}$. But! Then using the assumption from v) again,

$\theta \leq d(conv\{x_1,...,x_n\}, conv\{x_{n+1},...\}) \leq ||y-z|| < \frac{2\theta}{3}$.

And we are done.

Hope this is interesting to you- I really like the proof; but my problem still remains with the application of Hahn Banach, and the tiny point towards the end with the convex subsets that I put in *italics*.

EDIT#2

Requested proof for Lemma 2:

Let $f_1,f_2,...,f_n \in X^*$ be a basis for $E$. Let $T:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be the linear functional $T(x)=(f_i(x))_{i=1}^n$. Also, let $C=\{ Tx | ||x||<M\}$

Clearly, T is continuous. First, we show that T is onto. Suppose the contrary. Then $\exists \mathbf{a} = (a_1,a_2,...a_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n\ \{0\}$ such that $T:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n - span(\mathbf{a})$. But by taking the projection onto this subspace, we have $\Sigma_{i=1}^n a_if_i(x) = 0 \ \forall x\in X$ i.e. $\Sigma_{i=1}^n a_if_i = 0$ which contradicts $\{f_i\}$ being a basis.

Since $T$ is a continuous, linear, surjective map between Banach Spaces, we can use the Open Mapping Theorem to say that $C$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Moreover, $C$ is clearly convex. Now we want to show that $(\phi(f_i))_{i=1}^n \in C$. Assume the converse. We use  the -disjoint point and open convex set- version of Hahn Banach separation theorem to say that $\exists g\in S_{\mathbb{R}^{n*}}$ such that $g(\phi(f_i))_{i=1}^n > g(\mathbf{y}) \forall \mathbf{y}\in C$. That is, letting $g=(b_1,...,b_n) \neq \mathbf{0}$, we have $\Sigma b_if_i(x) < \Sigma b_i\phi(f_i) = \phi(\Sigma b_if_i) \forall ||x||<M$

Now we take norms. Regarding $\Sigma b_if_i$ as a linear operator $X\rightarrow \mathbf{R}$, and noting that $||\Sigma b_if_i|| := sup\{|\Sigma b_if_i(x)| : x\in S_X\}$, we must have $||\Sigma b_if_i||M \leq ||\phi||||(\Sigma b_if_i)||$ and since $(\Sigma b_if_i)\neq \mathbf{0}$ we have $M\leq ||\phi||$, a contradiction.

Comment: See Theorem 12.3 in Functional Analysis, by Bachman and Narici

Comment: I am interested in this question, could you post the entire solution?

Comment: @DaniloGregorin I will do as soon as I can- probably tomorrow

Comment: @DaniloGregorin I have now written out the full theorem and proof. I hope this is interesting to you! I was wondering if you could write the Theorem 12.3 you mentioned in an answer. I do not have access to that text (I have tried to obtain it by requesting my library to get online access, but they said they couldn't). Unforunately library books are also isolating in these times.

Comment: @DaniloGregorin Also, if you do happen to go through the proof and can comment on the additional isse in italics, that would be great.

Comment: Dear @Meep, thank you very much for your effort. I will take a time to go through this tomorrow, is it ok for you? I am a little busy today. In the meantime, email me at danilo.afonso.g@gmail.com and I can send you a .pdf of the book.

Comment: Could you give another hit on the proof of Lemma 2?

Comment: I think I managed a constructive proof of Lemma 2, without using Hahn-Banahc.

Comment: Hahn-Banach says there exists a norm-preserving extension $f$ of  $g.$ It does not say there are no non-norm preserving extensions of $g$... But if $X$ is not dense in $X^{**}$ then take $v\in X^{**}$ \ $\bar X$ and $0\ne r \in \Bbb R$.  For scalar $s$ and $x\in X$ let $g(sv+x)=sr.$ Let $Z=\{sv+x: s\in S\}$ where $S=\Bbb R$ or $S=\Bbb C.$ Then $0\ne g\in Z^*.$ By H-B there exists $h\in (X^{**})^*$ with $h|_Z=g.$ Now let $f=h/\|h\|.$ Then $\|f\|=1$ and $f|_X=0.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are assuming that $X$ is not reflexive. Then $J(B_X)$ is not dense in $B_{X^{**}}$ and hence $J(X)$ is not dense in $X^{**}$ (see Remark 15, chapter 3 of Brezis). Then, by Corollary 1.8 of the same book, there exists such a $T$.

Regarding your second question: Recall that if $x \in \overline{C_1}$ then $d(x, C_1) = 0$.